# utf-8 encoding not working on the banner of the webpage

Tags: asp.net, html, encoding, utf-8, master-pages

I got a really strange error on some of the webpages I am taking care of.

The banner is not showing the special character properly (ie: é, è, etc.). The catch is that this is only happening in the banner part of the master page. The rest of the page is always showing the characters the way they should but for some reason here is the text I get in the banner:

**Conseil de la radiodiffusion et des t�l�communications canadiennes**
ON the fourm, they are question mark, but on the page, they are the character not found squares.

this is what it should be showing:
**Conseil de la radiodiffusion et des télécommunications canadiennes**

It is an asp.net 4.0 page. The master page is getting the banner from an html file on the server.

- I tried deleting and recreating the said file and forcing the utf-8 encoding while saving it with vs2010.
- I tried forcing the utf-8 encoding in the web.config with no results.
- I tried forcing the utf-8 encoding in the master page with no results.

I really do not think it is the file though since most of the page does not have any problem with the spacial characters. The file is coded right (ascii special characters code like &eacu; are used instead of the character itself).

I think it is something when the master page go get the file to display it but I do not understand nor see how to fix this issue.

thanks

Comment: when you say 'in the banner' can you be more specific?

Comment: @Sparky672 
0%, well I've ask two questions, and one anser was in the comment, so I could not accept it, and the other one is still unanswered. Also, I did not create an account, and stackoverflow thinks i'm using another account because i switched from opera to ff 4.0.

@Adam Tuliper
The banner is the header of teh page. There is an image with text over it. And the navigation menu. IN the text over the image, it is  there that the text is displaying the square symbols insteand of teh character

Comment: [Two questions? Are these six questions not yours?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/706635/hugo)  Typically, if you don't get an acceptable answer from somebody, you would post an answer yourself and just accept that.

Comment: @Sparky672
you are right, I thought hat since my points and "award" were resetted, so was the account. Looks like not, I did post/accept answers for teh 4 other questions. the two left are still unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was a redundacy problem, the file is being stored at 5 or so different places, I found the right one and modified it.